# Docker compose build/Docker build connection refused to nuget at macos

Tags: c#, azure, docker, nuget

I've got a problem with building .NET 5 solutions using docker compose build or docker build.
Image which i'm using for building is:
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim
The problem is that when I'm trying to build it on my machine (MacOS Monterey, intel) I've got following error with restoring nuget packages from the private feed:

> #19 6.349   Failed to download package 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.4.5.1' from 'https://XXXX.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/96ca4348-f8c1-4150-b19f-3dab0cf807bf/nuget/v3/flat2/system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe/4.5.1/system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe.4.5.1.nupkg'.
> #19 6.349   Connection refused (pyvvsblobprodsu6weus63.blob.core.windows.net:443)
> #19 6.349     Connection refused
> #19 6.357   Failed to download package 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common.11.2.3' from 'https://XXXX.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/96ca4348-f8c1-4150-b19f-3dab0cf807bf/nuget/v3/flat2/microsoft.azure.storage.common/11.2.3/microsoft.azure.storage.common.11.2.3.nupkg'.
> #19 6.357   Connection refused (wg0vsblobprodsu6weus89.blob.core.windows.net:443)
> #19 6.357     Connection refused

I'm copying nuget.config with credentials in dockerfile like

> COPY nuget.config /

Here is my nuget.config copied to the container:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <add key="NuGet V3" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
        <add key="DDDDD" value="https://XXXX.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/DDDDD/nuget/v3/index.json" />
    </packageSources>
  <solution>
    <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
  </solution>
  <config>
     <add key="repositoryPath" value="packages" />
  </config>
    <packageSourceCredentials>
      <DDDDD>
      <add key="Username" value="SomeUsername" />
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="SomePassword" />
    </DDDDD>
</packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

Commands which i'm using to build containers:
docker compose up -d
docker build . -F API/Dockerfile
It's failing for both of them.

Can anybody tell me what's wrong? Maybe it's something with my machine setup?

Comment: Do the same build commands work successfully from a command line outside of docker?

Comment: Yes it was working as expected, i found answer for my problem and posted it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self answer for people having the same issue as I had:
The problem was the lack of this line in the nuget config:

in config section like:

```
<config>
    <add key='maxHttpRequestsPerSource' value='10' />
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="packages" />
</config>
```

After adding this key, everything is working as expected.
Keep in mind that your value for maxHttpRequestsPerSource may be different (less or more) so I advise doing a few experiments with other values.